# how to have variable row height in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to create a recyclerview in a nav drawer with the header showing the profile information. I would like to have a header height more than the other row elements. below is my header layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@color/green"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="XXXXX"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I set this to the header of the recycler view , the 200dp height is not reflecting in the UI

```
 RecyclerView.Adapter<NavDrawerListViewHolder> adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(this,TITLES,this);
        navList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Below is the adapter for the recyclerview :

```
public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NavDrawerListViewHolder> {

    private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
    Context mContext;
    String[] mCharacterList;
    IListItemClickListener mListener;
    int holderViewType=0;

    public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context, String[] characters, IListItemClickListener clickListener) {
        mContext = context;
        mCharacterList = characters;
        mListener = clickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public NavDrawerListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        NavDrawerListViewHolder viewHolder;
        holderViewType = viewType;
        if(viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.header,null);
            viewHolder = new NavDrawerListViewHolder(v,TYPE_HEADER,mListener);
        } else  {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.nav_item_row,null);
            viewHolder = new NavDrawerListViewHolder(v,TYPE_ITEM,mListener);
        }

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NavDrawerListViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if(holderViewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
            Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "Roboto-Thin.ttf");
            holder.name.setTypeface(typeface);
        } else {
            holder.characterName.setText(mCharacterList[position - 1]);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return TYPE_HEADER;
        }

        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mCharacterList.length + 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Replace:

```
LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.header,null);
```

with:

```
LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.header, parent, false);
```

and the same for all your other `inflate()` calls. If you know the parent container for the layout being inflated, always supply it to the `inflate()` call. In particular, `RelativeLayout` needs this, if it is the root view of the layout being inflated.

Also, consider using `getLayoutInflater()` on the `Activity` instead of `LayoutInflater.from()`. It may be that if you pass the `Activity` into `from()` that you will get equivalent results. However, in general, you always want to use a `LayoutInflater` that knows about the `Activity` and its theme, so you get the right results.